# What are the members of a qmake install set?

Tags: qt, qmake

```
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs
```

To help in the install process qmake has the concept of a `install set`.

It looks like a install set have members, i.e. `path`, `files` and `extra`:

```
documentation.path = /usr/local/program/doc
documentation.files = docs/*
```

Are there other members?

What members need to be set in order to consider the install set fully described?

Where the `create_docs` come from in the case below

```
unix:documentation.extra = create_docs; mv master.doc toc.doc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMake is documented... not. Whenever you want to know something you go browse source code. In this case, it's in `qmake/generators/makefile.cpp`, function `Makefilegenerator::writeInstalls()`.

As we can see, it's `path`, `files`, `base`, `extra`, `CONFIG`, `uninstall` and `depends`. `extra` (or `commands`) is an arbitrary line to insert at the top.

> What members need to be set in order to consider the install set fully described?

QMake is Makefile generator. Whatever human does it simply outputs some Makefile. Whether it will work or not, that's a human's problem.